# How to get an url from nsITraceableChannel?

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon

So, after reading [nsITraceableChannel](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/NsITraceableChannel) and 
[nsITraceableChannel, Intercept HTTP Traffic](http://www.softwareishard.com/blog/firebug/nsitraceablechannel-intercept-http-traffic/), and starring at

```
observe: function(aSubject, aTopic, aData) {
    if (aTopic == "http-on-examine-response") {
        var newListener = new TracingListener();
        aSubject.QueryInterface(Ci.nsITraceableChannel);
        newListener.originalListener = aSubject.setNewListener(newListener);
    }
}
```

I now wonder: how to get an exact url from aSubject? It says something about nsIHttpChannel, but I don't know how to get to that either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`nsIChannel` has an [`.URI` member](http://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/0aaa2d3d15cc/netwerk/base/public/nsIChannel.idl#l47) which you can query. You'll still need to QI to `nsIChannel` or any of the true sub-interfaces (`nsITraceableChannel` does not inherit from `nsIChannel` despite the name).

```
aSubject = aSubject.QueryInterface(Ci.nsIChannel);
var uri = aSubject.URI;
// original URI that was requested before any other resolver steps
// and/or redirects.
var ouri = aSubject.originalURI;
```

*Edit*
`QueryInterface()` sure returns something. Following the contract it returns a reference to `this` cast to the requested interface (if implemented). The JS-XPCOM bridge picks up on it and therefore stores in the JS-wrapper that an object implements a certain interface (same happens with `instanceof` BTW).

```
ch = Services.io.newChannel("https://google.com/", null, null);
console.log(ch.toString());
// "[xpconnect wrapped nsIChannel]"

ch.QueryInterface(Ci.nsITraceableChannel); 
console.log(ch.toString());
// "[xpconnect wrapped (nsISupports, nsIChannel, nsITraceableChannel)]"

console.log(ch instanceof Ci.nsIUploadChannel);
// true
console.log(ch.toString());
// "[xpconnect wrapped (nsISupports, nsIChannel, nsITraceableChannel, nsIUploadChannel)]"
// the variable "ch" is known to implement the four given interfaces at this point.
```

So, practically you don't need to store the result of `.QueryInterface`, but it is common practice that you do. Also, using the result of the call may come handy if an object implements multiple interfaces that define the same (from the point-of-view of JS) methods.

You cannot query two interfaces with one call. But I don't think there is any issue with doing multiple `.QueryInterface()` (and/or `instanceof`) calls.

Comment: hm... Is it possible to get both nsIChannel and nsITraceableChannel at the same time? I need first only to filter by url and response code. And, is QueryInterface actually returns anything?

Comment: Amended my answer discussing the questions in your comment.