# nsITraceableChannel, Intercept HTTP Traffic code

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon

Ive been trying to get this code working for firefox, that I got from
[nsITraceableChannel, Intercept HTTP Traffic](http://www.softwareishard.com/blog/firebug/nsitraceablechannel-intercept-http-traffic/#comment-15397) and from [How to get an url from nsITraceableChannel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25362347/how-to-get-an-url-from-nsitraceablechannel), Ive been googling for the answer, with no luck.
What I would like to do is intercept certain links, and change them.
Any help is welcomed

The error I get is **function statement requires a name** witch points to **observe: function(aSubject, aTopic, aData)** part of the code

```js
 const Cc = Components.classes;
const Ci = Components.interfaces;

var observerService = Cc["@mozilla.org/observer-service;1"]
    .getService(Ci.nsIObserverService);

observerService.addObserver(httpRequestObserver,
    "http-on-examine-response", false);

observerService.removeObserver(httpRequestObserver,
    "http-on-examine-response");
//--------------------------------------------------------

 var httpRequestObserver =
{
    observe: function(aSubject, aTopic, aData)
    {
        if (aTopic == "http-on-examine-response")
        {
        }
    },

    QueryInterface : function (aIID)
    {
        if (aIID.equals(Ci.nsIObserver) ||
            aIID.equals(Ci.nsISupports))
        {
            return this;
        }

        throw Components.results.NS_NOINTERFACE;

    }
}

//------------------------------------------------------------

 function TracingListener() {
    this.originalListener = null;
}

TracingListener.prototype =
{
    onDataAvailable: function(request, context, inputStream, offset, count) {
        this.originalListener.onDataAvailable(request, context, inputStream, offset, count);
    },

    onStartRequest: function(request, context) {
        this.originalListener.onStartRequest(request, context);
    },

    onStopRequest: function(request, context, statusCode) {
        this.originalListener.onStopRequest(request, context, statusCode);
    },

    QueryInterface: function (aIID) {
        if (aIID.equals(Ci.nsIStreamListener) ||
            aIID.equals(Ci.nsISupports)) {
            return this;
        }
        throw Components.results.NS_NOINTERFACE;
    }
}

observe: function(aSubject, aTopic, aData)
{
    if (aTopic == "http-on-examine-response") {
        var newListener = new TracingListener();
        aSubject.QueryInterface(Ci.nsITraceableChannel);
        newListener.originalListener = aSubject.setNewListener(newListener);
    }
}

aSubject = aSubject.QueryInterface(Ci.nsIChannel);
var uri = aSubject.URI;
// original URI that was requested before any other resolver steps
// and/or redirects.
var ouri = aSubject.originalURI;

ch = Services.io.newChannel("https://google.com/", null, null);
console.log(ch.toString());
// "[xpconnect wrapped nsIChannel]"

ch.QueryInterface(Ci.nsITraceableChannel); 
console.log(ch.toString());
// "[xpconnect wrapped (nsISupports, nsIChannel, nsITraceableChannel)]"

console.log(ch instanceof Ci.nsIUploadChannel);
// true
console.log(ch.toString());
// "[xpconnect wrapped (nsISupports, nsIChannel, nsITraceableChannel, nsIUploadChannel)]"
// the variable "ch" is known to implement the four given interfaces at this point.
```

Comment: Here's a yucky but working demo: https://github.com/Noitidart/demo-nsITraceableChannel/

Answer (score 0):

Copy paste this it works:

```
// const {classes: Cc, interfaces: Ci, utils: Cu, results: Cr} = Components;
// Cu.import('resource://gre/modules/Services.jsm');

Services.obs.addObserver(httpRequestObserver, "http-on-examine-response", false);

// Services.obs.removeObserver(httpRequestObserver, "http-on-examine-response");
//--------------------------------------------------------

var httpRequestObserver = {
    observe: function(aSubject, aTopic, aData) {
        // if (aTopic == "http-on-examine-response") {} // no need for this, we added observer for `http-on-examine-response` so we know for sure this only triggers for `http-on-examine-response`
        var newListener = new TracingListener();
        aSubject.QueryInterface(Ci.nsITraceableChannel);
        newListener.originalListener = aSubject.setNewListener(newListener);
    }
    /* // what was the point of this block of code?
    ,
    QueryInterface: function(aIID) {
        if (aIID.equals(Ci.nsIObserver) || aIID.equals(Ci.nsISupports)) {
            return this;
        }
        throw Cr.NS_NOINTERFACE;
    }
    */
}

//------------------------------------------------------------

function TracingListener() {}
TracingListener.prototype = {
    onDataAvailable: function(request, context, inputStream, offset, count) {
        console.log('data available');
        this.originalListener.onDataAvailable(request, context, inputStream, offset, count);
    },
    onStartRequest: function(request, context) {
        this.originalListener.onStartRequest(request, context);
    },
    onStopRequest: function(request, context, statusCode) {
        this.originalListener.onStopRequest(request, context, statusCode);
    },
    QueryInterface: function(aIID) {
        if (aIID.equals(Ci.nsIStreamListener) || aIID.equals(Ci.nsISupports)) {
            return this;
        }
        throw Cr.NS_NOINTERFACE;
    }
}

// what the hell? this is not part of an object? why observe colon?
/*
observe: function(aSubject, aTopic, aData) {
    if (aTopic == "http-on-examine-response") {
        var newListener = new TracingListener();
        aSubject.QueryInterface(Ci.nsITraceableChannel);
        newListener.originalListener = aSubject.setNewListener(newListener);
    }
}
*/

// whats with all this junk? is it supposed to be in an observer??
/*
aSubject = aSubject.QueryInterface(Ci.nsIChannel);
var uri = aSubject.URI;
// original URI that was requested before any other resolver steps
// and/or redirects.
var ouri = aSubject.originalURI;

ch = Services.io.newChannel("https://google.com/", null, null);
console.log(ch.toString());
// "[xpconnect wrapped nsIChannel]"

ch.QueryInterface(Ci.nsITraceableChannel);
console.log(ch.toString());
// "[xpconnect wrapped (nsISupports, nsIChannel, nsITraceableChannel)]"

console.log(ch instanceof Ci.nsIUploadChannel);
// true
console.log(ch.toString());
// "[xpconnect wrapped (nsISupports, nsIChannel, nsITraceableChannel, nsIUploadChannel)]"
// the variable "ch" is known to implement the four given interfaces at this point.
*/
```

## Update

Someone asked me how to get the response source with this, so I created a gist out of it: https://gist.github.com/Noitidart/d0b08629ee2804538ad9#file-_ff-addon-snippet-copyofrequestsource-js-L16