# how i can catch every request and see loading time?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

I want to do something like network tab in chrome developer tools. 
But using Observer i can catch each start request, if even you use it:

```
    observerService.addObserver(this, "http-on-examine-response", false);
    observerService.addObserver(this, "http-on-examine-cached-response", false);
    observerService.addObserver(this, "http-on-modify-request", false);
    observerService.addObserver(this, "http-on-opening-request", false);
    observerService.addObserver(this, "http-on-examine-merged-response", false);
```

How can I do it?

Comment: I'm just guessing but you get the open time in `http-on-modify-request` and the end time in `http-on-examine-reponse` :)But I think theres a better way, like that info is available to you. Because associatng two requests is a bit tricky, for this reason I think nsITraceableChannel is better, becuase it gives you the nsIRequest on top and you have that same request till it completes. But Firefox dev tools does it, so the easy way is search firefox codebase at https://dxr.mozilla.org and copy how they do it :) http://stackoverflow.com/a/31839310/1828637

Comment: The reason I recommneded `nsiTraceableChannel` is because its very easy they offer a `onStartRequest` and `onStopRequest`. There still may be better ways, which we can find by searching firefox codebase like mentioned in my preivous comment.

Answer (score 0):

nsITraceable channel, note the time in `onStartRequest` and note the final time in `onStopRequest`, copy paste examples: [nsITraceableChannel, Intercept HTTP Traffic code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31825090/nsitraceablechannel-intercept-http-traffic-code/31839310#31839310)